# Oracle SQL - group data by week between two date D1 and D2

Tags: sql, oracle

**#Oracle**
i have a records related to dates, and i would to group by week between two date D1 and D2.

My meeting table is,

```
id_Meeting | meeting_date 
-----------+--------------
1          | 07/04/2017
2          | 10/06/2017  
3          | 17/04/2017
4          | 08/05/2017
5          | 19/04/2017
6          | 12/05/2017
7          | 06/04/2017
8          | 04/04/2017
```

Now I print all rows like that between Date1=01/04/2017 and Date1=01/05/2017,

```
Week |  nb_meeting_by_week
-----+--------------------
w1   |  3
w2   |  0
w3   |  2
w4   |  3
```

Any ideas?

What i try me is,

```
Select 
  TRUNC((TO_DATE(m.meeting_date, 'YYYYMMDD') - TO_DATE('01/04/17', 'dd-MM-yy'))/7 +1)
    as week, 
  count(*) as nb_meeting_by_week
from meeting m 
Where TO_DATE(m.meeting_date, 'YYYYMMDD') between '01/04/17' and '01/05/17' 
Group by
  TRUNC((TO_DATE(m.meeting_date, 'YYYYMMDD') - TO_DATE('01/04/17', 'dd-MM-yy'))/7 +1);
```

But i don't get the second week [w2 | 0] because i don't have meeting in this week. But me i would have 0 for all weeks that have zero meetings.

Comment: The tags on this question indicate that you are looking in the right places. Have you seen a `GROUP BY` example somewhere on the net? Please edit the question to paste in the query you are trying and describe how it does or does not meet your expectations.

Comment: What i try me is,  Select TRUNC((TO_DATE(m.meeting_date, 'YYYYMMDD') - TO_DATE('01/04/17', 'dd-MM-yy'))/7 +1) as week, count(*) as nb_meeting_by_week from meeting m
Where TO_DATE(m.meeting_date, 'YYYYMMDD') between '01/04/17' and '01/05/17' Group by TRUNC((TO_DATE(m.meeting_date, 'YYYYMMDD') - TO_DATE('01/04/17', 'dd-MM-yy'))/7 +1); But i don't get the second week [w2 | 0] because i don't have meeting in this week. But me i would have 0 for all weeks that have zero meetings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must first generate all weeks on-the-fly, as they are not in your database (i.e. there isn't a record for every week in the table). This is done with a recursive query. Then outer join your table.

```
with weeks(weekno, from_date, max_date) as
(
  select 1 as weekno, date '2017-04-01' as from_date, date '2017-05-01' as max_date
  from dual  
  union all
  select weekno + 1 as weekno, from_date + 7 as from_date, max_date
  from weeks
  where from_date + 7 <= max_date
)
select weeks.weekno, count(mbw.meeting_date)
from weeks
left outer join nb_meeting_by_week mbw
  on  mbw.meeting_date >= weeks.from_date 
  and mbw.meeting_date <  weeks.from_date + 7
  and mbw.meeting_date <= weeks.max_date
group by weeks.weekno
order by weeks.weekno;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Select to_char(meeting_date, 'w'), count(*)
From your_table
Where date1 = your_date and date2 = your_date2
Group by to_char(meeting_date, 'w');
```

This is use of date functions. There are a lot of functions on dates.

That one will give you the number of the week in the month for the argument date.

Comment: i try this, Select to_char(TO_DATE(m.meeting_date, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'w'), count(*) from meeting m
Where TO_DATE(m.meeting_date, 'YYYYMMDD') between '01/04/17' and '01/05/17' Group by to_char(TO_DATE(m.meeting_date, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'w'); But i don't get the second week [w2 | 0] because i don't have meeting in this week. But me i would have 0 for all weeks that have zero meetings.

Comment: So add right join with (select level lvl from dual connect by level <= 4 ) on to_char(lvl) = to_char(meeting_date, 'w'). This will force 4 weeks for the month (you can use 5 instead of 4, for months with 5 weeks. If you want it dynamiclly for each month, you will need to do another addition).

Comment: I test why you proposed and not fontionned yet. However,  it works perfectly with what @Thorsten Kettner had proposed.  Thanks by the way.